# After quit of excel in Access process stil shows in task manager until Quit access completely

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, taskmanager

I am having an issue with excel showing in the task manager processes after quit.  I have searched many different answers to still have the process show in task manager.  I have other vba code in other functions that open and close excel just fine and removes from processes, but the current event I am running below just leaves the process in the task manager until I quit access completely. Please Help!!

```
 Private Sub status_ID_AfterUpdate()
 On Error GoTo Problems
 Dim filename As String
 Dim NewStatus As Long

 filename = "M:\Shared Documents\Job Cost Analysis\Hospital Active B2B Cases.xlsx" 

 Dim cell As Range
 Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
 Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
 Dim ws As Worksheet

 Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
 With xlApp
    .Visible = True
    Set xlWB = .Workbooks.Open(filename, , False)
    Set ws = .Worksheets("Active B2B cases")

ws.Columns("B:B").Select
Set cell = Selection.Find(What:=Me.client_ID.Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If cell Is Nothing Then
'do nothing
Else
'Update active B2B sheet

If Me.status_ID.column(0) = "FINAL PROCESSING" Then
ws.Range("E" & (xlApp.cell.Row)).Value = "Final Processing"
MsgBox "The client's status has been updated on the Active B2B sheet"
ElseIf Me.status_ID.column(0) = "DATA ENTRY" Then
ws.Range("E" & (xlApp.cell.Row)).Value = "Data Entry"
MsgBox "The client's status has been updated on the Active B2B sheet"
ElseIf Me.status_ID.column(0) = "COMPLIANCE REVIEW" Then
ws.Range("E" & (xlApp.cell.Row)).Value = "Available To Audit"
MsgBox "The client's status has been updated on the Active B2B sheet"
ElseIf Me.status_ID.column(0) = "SENIOR COMPLIANCE REVIEW" Then
ws.Range("E" & (xlApp.cell.Row)).Value = "2nd Level Review"
MsgBox "The client's status has been updated on the Active B2B sheet"
ElseIf Me.status_ID.column(0) = "WAITING FOR DOCUMENTATION" Then
ws.Range("E" & (xlApp.cell.Row)).Value = "Pending - Doc"
MsgBox "The client's status has been updated on the Active B2B sheet"
ElseIf Me.status_ID.column(0) = "INVOICED" Then
xlApp.cell.EntireRow.Delete
MsgBox "The client has been removed from the Active B2B sheet"
End If

End If

End With
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
xlWB.SaveAs (filename)
xlWB.Close
xlApp.Quit

Set cell = Nothing
DoEvents
Set ws = Nothing
DoEvents
Set xlWB = Nothing
DoEvents
Set xlApp = Nothing
DoEvents
Exit Sub

Problems:
Err.Clear

Resume Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I vaguely remember that using `Selection` can cause this. Try `Set cell = ws.Columns("B:B").Find(What:= ...` (or with an additional Range variable).

Comment: what happens if you `xlWB.Close True`? Sometimes explicitly passing that `SaveChanges` parameter can help.

Comment: What happens if you comment out your error handler?

Comment: And I find your usage of `xlApp.cell` confusing. `cell` is a local variable in your sub - are you trying to reference that?

Comment: @Andre normally I don't precede with the xlApp but seen in another post to add, it works with or without the xlApp but still leaves excel in processes

Comment: I still think it's wrong, but anyway. Did you try the other comments?

Comment: Yes I also removed the preceding `xlApp` from `xlApp.cell` but still showing in processes. I did notice that if it doesn't go through the else statement it closes fine because no changes were made. This is a protected worksheet that if it is open by a user and another tries to open it , it is read only, so not sure as if that has anything to do with it hanging in the processes... But I am running the code when it is not open by another user.

Answer (score 0):

At least until a better solution comes along, you could add this to the end of your code(after setting variables equal to Nothing).  Note: this will terminate all instances of Excel on your machine.

```
Call Shell("taskkill.exe /f /im excel.exe", vbNormalFocus)
```

Comment: I thought of this but like you mentioned it kills all open excel workbooks, which I don't want as users could have other excel files open that they are working on